# 'this' included in MethodInfo.Invoke for static method (by Mono BCL)

Tags: .net, reflection, delegates, clr, base-class-library

Background: I'm working on a domain-specific CLI implementation.  This implementation is hopefully going to use the BCL included with Mono or parts thereof.  It does not use any other part of Mono - it implements the CLR/VES itself from scratch.  Right now I'm studying the "boundary layer" between the CLR itself and the BCL, so I can make sure my CLR will act the way the BCL expects it to.

I've bumped into something in the Mono BCL source code I'm having some difficulty understanding.  It is in the implementation of `System.Delegate`:

```
        ...
        private object m_target;
        ...
        public MethodInfo Method {
            ...
        }
        ...

#if NET_2_0
        public object DynamicInvoke (params object[] args)
#else
        public object DynamicInvoke (object[] args)
#endif
        {
            return DynamicInvokeImpl (args);
        }

        protected virtual object DynamicInvokeImpl (object[] args)
        {
            if (Method == null) {
                Type[] mtypes = new Type [args.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i) {
                    mtypes [i] = args [i].GetType ();
                }
                method_info = m_target.GetType ().GetMethod (data.method_name, mtypes);
            }

#if NET_2_0
            if ((m_target != null) && Method.IsStatic) {
                // The delegate is bound to m_target
                if (args != null) {
                    object[] newArgs = new object [args.Length + 1];
                    args.CopyTo (newArgs, 1);
                    newArgs [0] = m_target;
                    args = newArgs;
                } else {
                    args = new object [] { m_target };
                }
                return Method.Invoke (null, args);
            }
#endif

            return Method.Invoke (m_target, args);
        }
```

I'm looking at `DynamicInvokeImpl`.  The first bit is clear: it's getting the `MethodInfo` based on the signature being called.

Things get strange after the second `#if NET_2_0`.  It looks like if a target object was supplied, and the method being called *is static*, it *adds a 'this' pointer to the arguments!*

It goes on to pass this possibly modified argument list to `MethodInfo.Invoke`.  I've looked at the MSDN documentation for this method and it seems pretty clear that even calling on an *instance* method, you're *not* supposed to include a 'this' pointer - let alone adding one on for a *static* method!

Keep in mind, this is *not* calling some internal piece of Mono that could work whatever way they want it to - it's calling a well-defined public method in `System.Reflection.MethodInfo`!

I am aware that the CLR has to insert a hidden argument - typically a type handle - into static method calls on *generic* classes.  However, 1) this is a 'this' reference, not a type handle, 2) the code appears to be doing it wholesale, not just for *generic* classes, and 3) anything like that would be done at a lower level, not by a caller of `MethodInfo.Invoke`!

Any clue what is going on here?

Comment: Is that a weird way to implement extension methods?

Comment: @hawk Interesting point.  I never thought of that.  I'm thinking if so this is extremely non-compliant.  I'm pretty sure extension methods are supposed to be resolved to static calls _by the language compiler_.

Comment: @hawk On second thought, I can't even see how that would work, considering that extension methods are members of a _separate_ helper class, not the type of the instance they're being called on.

Comment: Extension methods are purely a C# feature. The CLI does not know about them at all.

Answer (score 0):

When would a delegate to a static method have a target?

I don't think it can happen with normal C# or VB.NET. However, there is an overload of `Delegate.CreateDelegate` that says: "Creates a delegate of the specified type that represents the specified static or instance method, **with the specified first argument**." with **my emphasis**, obviously.

Reading the description for the argument called `firstArgument`, it says: "The object to which the delegate is bound, or `null` to treat method as `static` (`Shared` in Visual Basic).", but the code we see in the OP suggests this is not the case.

<strike>(BTW I think it's a bug and should say `!Method.IsStatic`.)</strike> This has been documented as a feature [since .NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3860fy3(v=vs.80).aspx).

This code shows we can exercise this:

```vb
Module Module1
Class DelegateTest
    Shared Sub Test(ByVal arg1 As Object, ByVal arg2 As Object)
        Console.WriteLine("arg1: {0}: {1}", If(arg1 IsNot Nothing, arg1.GetType.Name, "Nothing"), arg1)
        Console.WriteLine("arg2: {0}: {1}", If(arg2 IsNot Nothing, arg2.GetType.Name, "Nothing"), arg2)
    End Sub
End Class
Delegate Sub TestDelegate(ByVal arg1 As Object, ByVal arg2 As Object)
Delegate Sub TestDelegate2(ByVal arg2 As Object)
Sub Main()
    Dim a As TestDelegate = AddressOf DelegateTest.Test
    a.DynamicInvoke("A arg1", "A arg2")
    Dim dt = New DelegateTest
    Dim b As New TestDelegate(AddressOf dt.Test)
    b.DynamicInvoke("B Arg1", "B Arg2")
    a = DirectCast(TestDelegate.CreateDelegate(GetType(TestDelegate), GetType(DelegateTest).GetMethod("Test", Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)), TestDelegate)
    a.DynamicInvoke("A Arg1", "A Arg2")
    Dim c As TestDelegate = DirectCast(TestDelegate.CreateDelegate(GetType(TestDelegate), Nothing, GetType(DelegateTest).GetMethod("Test", Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)), TestDelegate)
    c.DynamicInvoke("C ARG1", "C ARG2")

    Dim d As TestDelegate2 = DirectCast(TestDelegate2.CreateDelegate(GetType(TestDelegate2), "D A1", GetType(DelegateTest).GetMethod("Test", Reflection.BindingFlags.Static Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)), TestDelegate2)
    d.DynamicInvoke("D A2")
    d("D A2") ' Just confirming there's nothing special about DynamicInvoke here.

    If Debugger.IsAttached Then _
      Console.ReadLine()

End Sub

End Module
```

This compiles and outputs:

> arg1: String: A arg1
>   arg2: String: A arg2
>   arg1: String: B Arg1
>   arg2: String: B Arg2
>   arg1: String: A Arg1
>   arg2: String: A Arg2
>   arg1: String: C ARG1
>   arg2: String: C ARG2
>   arg1: String: D A1
>   arg2: String: D A2
>   arg1: String: D A1
>   arg2: String: D A2

- `a` is just a default static delegate, and is recreated the long way with `.CreateDelegate`.
- `b` just shows the unneeded instance is ignored (and there's a warning to that effect).
- `c` attempted to use the interesting overload, but it required `null` (`Nothing`) at runtime to not throw a method bind error on creation.
- `d` shows the overload doing what we see the code is enabling, and I confirm it is not limited to `DynamicInvoke`.

This is compiled with .NET 3.5/2.0 using VS2k8.